# How can I arrange an array of times in ascending order using Twig?

Tags: sorting, date, twig, octobercms, craftcms

I have a list of dates and times in the CMS that need to be organised in ascending order.
What is it that I need to check for?
I think I need to use `|sort` but the documentation for twig isn't really clear on how to use it for a newbie to development.

```
{% if inspectionDates|length %}
<h4 class="column__title">Inspection times</h4>
<ul class="column__timelist">
{% for inspection in inspectionDates %}
    <li>
        <span>{{ inspection.date|date('l j F') }}</span>
        <span class="column__hours">{{ inspection.startTime|date('g:i') }}<i>{{ inspection.startTime|date('A') }}</i> - {{ inspection.endTime|date('g:i') }}<i>{{ inspection.endTime|date('A') }}</i></span>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

Can you please explain like I'm 5 how it works and the logic around sorting by date?

Comment: Twig is not providing such a good sorting functionality So It's better to sort the `inspectionDates ` from backend where you have done queries.

Comment: ^ or add a custom twig filter

Comment: @DarkBee can you tell me what you mean by custom twig filter? I've been assigned to do this as a frontend feature

Comment: See [here](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/extend/extending-twig.html#register-a-twig-extension) and [here](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/advanced.html#creating-an-extension). After u've created your own extension you can add a filter e.g. `sort_by_time` and use it inside twig like `{% for inspection in inspectionDates | sort_by_time %}`